# UIView not displaying the way it should

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, uiview

```
CGRect frame = bottomView.frame;

frame.origin.y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height + 88;
bottomView.frame = frame;
NSLog(@"bottom view frame is %f", bottomView.frame.origin.y);
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self bottomButtonsCustomLoad];
```

I also have the line

```
frame.origin.y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height + 88;
```

nested inside an "If" statement and both log 579 which should display the view but the one inside the if statement the uiview isn't visible it logs 579 but isn't there it seems to be below the window which is where it starts before animation

Answer (score 0):

If you set the y origin to the height of the screen it seems normal that your view is not visible, since it'll be outside of the screen (at the bottom).

Remember the point (0,0) is the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show puts the window at 88 points below the bottom edge of the screen, so it seems right that it does not show. If you meant for the view to be 88 points below the top edge, it should be

```
frame.origin.y = 88
```